# Use same instance of Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am making a game, and i want to use the same Activity every time when a user fails the Level and i don't wanna create all the Views every time when the FailedActivity is shown.

For example i have Level1Activity:

```
public class Level1Activity extends Activity{

   private static final int REQUEST_FAIL_ACTIVITY = 10;
   private static final int RESULT_RETRY_LEVEL= 11;
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedIntanceState){
       ...
   }

   public void showFailedActivity(){
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, FailedActivity);
       intent.putExtra("text1", "You failed! You made only 50 points");
       intent.putExtra("text2", "Try again later");
       startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_FAIL_ACTIVITY );
   }

   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == REQUEST_FAIL_ACTIVITY ){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_BACK){
                finish();
            }else if(resultCode == RESULT_RETRY_LEVEL){
                retryLevel();
            }else{
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And class FailedActivity

```
    private RelativeLayout bgLayout;
    private TextView text1;
    private TextView text2;
    private TextView text3;
    private TextView text4;
    private TextView text5;
    private Button buttonRetryLevel;
    private Button buttonBack;

    public class FailedActivity extends Activity{
        public void onCreate(Bundle saved){
           super.onCreate(saved)

           setContentView(R.layout.activity_failed);
           bgLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.bgLayout);
           text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
           ...
           buttonBack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);

           Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
           text1.setText(bundle.getString("text1");
           ...
           text5.setText(bundle.getString("text5);

        }

     public void buttonRetryClicked(View view){
        setResult(Level1Activity.RESULT_RETRY_LEVEL);
        finish();
     }

     ...
}
```

So, i want to call findViewById for all the Views only once, and reuse the Activity because the FailedActivity i use for all my Levels, i need to pass only the Strings that will be shown, maybe the background color, etc.

My question is: can i create the FailedActivity only ones, and then when i call startActivityForResult just to pass the Bundle and the Views to be created only once.

Comment: Use android:launchMode="singleTop" inside <activity> tag of Manifest file.

Comment: I don't understand your question, it seems you already are doing what you ask.

Comment: @AndroidDev - i tried to do that, but it still calling onCreate method, so the Views are reinitializating

Comment: @njzk2 - i am showing a lot of time the FailedActivity. Every time when the Activity is shown, the UI components (TextViews, RelativeLayout, Buttons) are initializating every time, so i want to initialize only one time all the UI Components, and every time when the FailedActivity is shown, just to change the text, background, etc

Comment: Override onNewIntent() in your activity ,it will be called whenever a new intent enters to your activity , in this case inCreate() won't call.

Comment: If onCreate() is being called then your activity is being destroyed due to some reasons.

Comment: why do you even care that the views are being re-created? is there a specific performance issue that you can see?

Comment: @AndroidDev i overrided the method onNewIntent and is still calling the onCreate(). I want something like what does a ViewHolder for RecyclerView..

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> singleInstance

as launch mode and override onNewIntent() function to bypass the re-creation of the activity UI components.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    // handle parameters here.
}
```

Comment: i made that. The method onCreate should be called only once. Right? But the method onCreate is calling every time..

Comment: You can't tell to the system to keep in memory the activity. If it needs to be recreated, it will be.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible as noted in the another answer. If you do this though, you are stepping outside of the standard Activity lifecycle. Generally, when an android app starts a new Activity, the old Activity is destroyed and a new instance of the new one is created. This also occurs when you change the device orientation (portrait -> landscape). The Android runtime does this for memory efficiency and because the view dimensions may have changed. Have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) if you want to learn more about the activity lifecycle.

Are the bundled values you're putting in an intent from your Level1Activity going to be the same for other levels? If so you could hardcode those strings directly into the xml layout file for FailedActivity. If you need all level activities to have the ability to open the FailedActivity, I'd consider creating a levelActivity superclass.  This will simplify the FailedActivity creation code and stop you from having to repeat yourself. Something like this:

```
public abstract class LevelActivity extends Activity {
    public void showFailedActivity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FailedActivity);
        intent.putExtra("text1", "You failed! You made only 50 points");
        intent.putExtra("text2", "Try again later");
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_FAIL_ACTIVITY );
    }
}

public class Level1Activity extends LevelActivity {
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_FAIL_ACTIVITY ){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_BACK){
            finish();
        }else if(resultCode == RESULT_RETRY_LEVEL){
            super.retryLevel(); // calls LevelActivity.retryLevel()
        }else{
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```